# How to check for no errors in jquery .validate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I am having some issues creating the code which should show a button only if all the text fields validate correctly.  I am hiding the button when page opens (i know I can use css to do this but I am just trying to work out the functionality) and I want to show the button when the fields are correct.  I am trying to use the success option, but it is just showing the button immediately before anything is filled out.  Any suggestions?  Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js\jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var submit = false;
$(".btn").hide();
 $("#submission").validate({
   rules: {
      appSize: { 
         required:true,
         max:12 },
      appName: { 
         required:true,
         rangelength:[4,9] },
      appPrice: { 
         required:true,
         min:.99,
         max:3.99 },
      email: { 
         required:true,
         email:true }
   },

   messages: { 
      appSize: {
      required: "App Size is a required field"},
      appName: { 
         required: "App Name is a required field",
         rangelength: "The name must be between 4 and 9 characters" },
      appPrice: { 
         required: "App Price is a required field",
         min: "Price must be .99 or greater",
         max: "Price must be less than 3.99" },
      email: { 
         required: "email is a required field",
         email: "You must enter a valid email address" },
      success: submit = true

   },
   errorElement: "div",




 });
 if(submit)
    $(".btn").show();
 $(".btn").click(function() {

     alert("Data is Valid, Thanks for your submission");    
   });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="submission" method="post" action="#">
  <h1>Apple iPhone App Contest Submission Page</h1>
    <div id="theForm">
        <div>
                 <label for="appSize">What is the file size in KB?</label>
                 <input name="appSize" type="text" id="fileSize" class="required error"></input>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
                 <label for="appName">What is the App Name?</label>
                 <input name="appName" type="text" id="appName" class="required error"></input>
        </div>
        <br />
         <div>
                 <label for="appPrice">What is the App Price?  $</label>
                 <input name="appPrice" type="text" id="appPrice" class="required error"></input>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
                 <label for="email">Submitters Email Address</label>
                 <input name="email" type="text" id="email" class="required error"></input>
        </div>
        <br /> 
       <input type="button" class="btn" value="Submit"></input>
     </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had to work around the original since I couldnt get much help.  here is my final project build:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
<meta name="created" content="Thu, 01 Dec 2011 17:34:38 GMT">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<style type="text/css">
   h1 {
   text-align:center;
   background: #7AC5CD;
   -moz-border-radius: 7px;
   border-radius: 7px;
   -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
   box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #55aaee, #003366);
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#55aaee), to(#003366));
   color: #000000; 
   height: auto; 
   padding: 5px;}
   form {
   background-color:#faefae;
   -moz-border-radius: 7px;
   border-radius: 7px;
   -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
   box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000; }
   body {
   background-color:#7AC5CD; }
   .required {
   border:inset; 
   position:absolute;
   left:200px;
   -moz-border-radius: 7px;
   border-radius: 7px;
   -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
   box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000; }
   .btn {
   position:absolute;
   left:600px;
   top:120px;
   width:125px;
   height:50px;
   font-size:larger;
   -moz-border-radius: 7px;
   border-radius: 7px;
   -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
   box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000; }
   div.error {
   font-size:large; 
   color:red;
   font-family:arial;
   font-style:italic;}
   .images {
   alignment-adjust:absolute;
   position:absolute;
   text-align:center; 
   left:450px;
   background:#7AC5CD;
   background-color:#7AC5CD;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js\jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submission").validate({
   rules: {
      appSize: { 
         required:true,
         max:12 },
      appName: { 
         required:true,
         rangelength:[4,9] },
      appPrice: { 
         required:true,
         min:.99,
         max:3.99 },
      email: { 
         required:true,
         email:true }
   },
   messages: { 
      appSize: {
      required: "App Size is a required field"},
      appName: { 
         required: "App Name is a required field",
         rangelength: "The name must be between 4 and 9 characters" },
      appPrice: { 
         required: "App Price is a required field",
         min: "Price must be .99 or greater",
         max: "Price must be less than 3.99" },
      email: { 
         required: "email is a required field",
         email: "You must enter a valid email address" }

   },
   errorElement: "div"


 });

});
</script>
     </head>
       <body>
         <form id="submission" method="post" action="#">
           <h1>Apple iPhone App Contest Submission Page</h1>
          <div id="theForm">
              <div>
                <label for="appSize">What is the file size in KB?</label>
                <input name="appSize" type="text" id="fileSize" class="required"></input>
              </div>
              <br />
              <div>
                <label for="appName">What is the App Name?</label>
                <input name="appName" type="text" id="appName" class="required"></input>
             </div>
             <br />
             <div>
                <label for="appPrice">What is the App Price?  $</label>
                <input name="appPrice" type="text" id="appPrice" class="required"></input>
             </div>
             <br />
             <div>
                     <label for="email">Submitters Email Address</label>
                     <input name="email" type="text" id="email" class="required"></input>
            </div>
            <br /> 
           <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit"/>
         </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: submit = true
```

That isn't going to work how you intend.

Assign a function to that property and do what you need to do in there.

Comment: I dont know that I am completely sure how to do that... this is the first time I have used a jquery validation plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a bit confused to me...
How do you think you could submit the form if you hide the submit button?
I think you could bind some "onchange" event to all your form inputs to call validation... but this could mean you will get validation to be fired even when you pass from an input to another while you're filling them.